# PST to CSV File Conversion

Tags: csv, outlook

Does anyone know of a good tool that converts .pst to .csv files through command line?

Answer (score 1):

Can you assume Outlook is installed on the computer? If so, I believe it can be background scripted using OLE or something similar. I've done file conversions through Excel using Ruby that way.

And here's a [Perl example](http://www.unur.com/comp/ppp/perl-win32-ole-outlook-ex1.html)

Answer (score 1):

A solution I just stumbled across is: 
[libpst](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/)

It obviously doesn't convert straight to CSV, but it converts into a more manageable format.

Importing into Outlook and then exporting as CSV is still probably the quickest solution, but libpst would certainly be useful if all you have is the PST file and no Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

one time only? or programmatically?

if one time only, import into a mail program that handles mbox (e.g. Thunderbird), at which point you just have text files, manipulate as desired.

otherwise, no idea, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a .Net application using CDO, MAPI, OOM or Redemption, that does what you need.
I've written a complete Outlook exporter tool for my company, which you can view at http://www.tzunami.com