# How to search a certain user's outlook inbox for items with a specific subject?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

Is there a way to search a certain user's outlook inbox to get all emails with a certain subject?
Required solution should work for Outlook 2007 and 2010.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want to be logged in as user X and access outlook for user Y? you can always connect to their .pst and run queries. You can use JET syntax.

Comment: @Dustin: Yes, there will be a generic user which can connect and access user Y outlook. But how to connect to their .pst and run queries? and what is JET syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look here [Can I read an Outlook (2003/2007) PST file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577904/can-i-read-an-outlook-2003-2007-pst-file-in-c) as well as the link that @SeanP provided

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look here?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508940%28v=office.12%29.aspx