# How can I access hidden contact properties when exporting to .csv vs .pst in Outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook-addin, pst

I want to export contacts from Outlook 2007 to a format which can be opened in plain-text for modifying using a program. When exported to .pst format and re-imported, the contacts seem to retain some hidden properties used by an Outlook addin like ID, etc. whereas when exported to csv, I do not see these fields anywhere in the csv file.

Is there any difference in what gets stored when exported to .pst vs. csv? How do I get these hidden properties on the contacts to be exported to csv?

Comment: For those that might vote to close - this question is about programatic integration with Outlook, not something that users at Superuser would be able to hlep with as much as users on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If what you say is true then it sounds like you should be attempting to read and modify the .pst file instead of exporting to .csv.

This question may be of assistance [Can I read an Outlook (2003/2007) PST file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577904/can-i-read-an-outlook-2003-2007-pst-file-in-c), although the method will be slightly different if you are using something other than C# / .Net.