# Convert Outlook PST file to XML

Tags: c#, vb.net

My final goal is to extract the outlook appointments from an Outlook PST file without the need of an Office installed, but since it's a very hard thing to do without a 3rd party Com control like "Independentsoft". I want to parse the PST file into an XML which I will extract the appointments out of it later.

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577904/can-i-read-an-outlook-2003-2007-pst-file-in-c

Comment: I already went through all the similar questions in here, this one is adding a store meaning he's adding PST content to outlook existing account. I want to parse the PST to something i can read from, like XML,Text etc.