# Opening PST files and storing the metadata

Tags: c#, pst

I have a a ton of PSTs and I need to be able to open them and get their metadata (Sender, date, time, message, subject).
I tried using code found here - [Can I read an Outlook (2003/2007) PST file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577904/can-i-read-an-outlook-2003-2007-pst-file-in-c)

I get an error when it gets to the line:

```
MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores[pstName].GetRootFolder();
```

It doesn't like what I have for my pst name.

I'd like to just be able to loop through all my psts without worrying what the file path and file name is.  Is this possible?

**Edit:** If it is possible, I'd like to eventually put it into a SQL database, but even a flat file (CSV or even XML or whatever else) will do.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly about your error, but you can convert your PST files into XML using XENA

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xena/?source=directory

Comment: if its not Not exactly about the error what is this really for?

Comment: To convert using another solution, not reading through C#. I mean, if C# is not a requirement you can try Xena.