# Save 'MailItem' object as .msg file

Tags: c#, outlook

Following from the code outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577904/can-i-read-an-outlook-2003-2007-pst-file-in-c/2521444#2521444)

How can I save the `MailItem` object as a `.msg` file?

Or another way to put this is: How can I create a `.msg` file using the attributes(sender, cc, bcc, subject, body, etc.) of a `MailItem` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mailItem.SaveAs(savepath);
```

Where mailItem is the Outlook MailItem and the savepath is for instance:

```
String savepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\" + filename + ".msg";
```

If you wish to use the MailItem subject as the filename you might want to remove invalid chars for filenames:

```
String filename = mailItem.Subject;
string invalid = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());

foreach (char c in invalid)
{
    filename = filename.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, I just wrote a pretty large outlook add-in myself which also contains this code.

Comment: I'll choose your answer for the extra info of raising the issue of invalid chars when using the subject as the filename. Thanks again Toon!

Answer (score 2):

Use `MailItem.SaveAs(..., olMsg)` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175283(v=office.12).aspx.

Or do you mean you want to create an MSG file from the scratch without an actual `MailItem` object residing in one of the Outlook folders? In that case you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) and its [RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) method (returns [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object).

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! this is what I was expecting >>Use MailItem.SaveAs(..., olMsg)!

Comment: would be nice if this was in C#. Currently this is COM object based.

Comment: What exactly are you having troubles translating to C#?