# Export a folder within PST to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, outlook, pst

I am trying to solve a problem with C#. I am able to import PST to outlook. Then use Import and Export option of Outlook to convert a folder within PST (chats) to CSV.
how can i do the same using C#? If there is anyone who can help me with the code or give me link to any reference, it would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577904/can-i-read-an-outlook-2003-2007-pst-file-in-c

Comment: Hi rufanov. I tried that method and it fails at MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores[pstName].GetRootFolder(); Infact i copied the entire code and verified.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Do you get any exception in the code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you want to export. Anyway, you may find the [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-fc170960) sample project helpful.

It looks like you need to iterate over all folders and grab the required information. The [How to: Enumerate Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184607(v=office.15).aspx) page is a good start for you.

Comment: Hi Eugene. I have a folder named Chats within PST. I need to convert that folder to CSV. I have around 100 PST's and each PST's has a folder named Chats. I need to repeat this process of creating  CSV to each of these folders

Comment: How do you want to convert a folder to a csv file? I.e. what data do you need to extract?

Comment: Right now i am manually exporting the folder under a PST to CSV. The folder has all instant messages logs. To, Sent, Messages etc are some of the data in it.

Comment: The CSV does have them as headers and u have data under these headers. I wanted to automate this process

Comment: It looks like you need to iterate over all stores and folder to find the Chats folder and extract the data.

Comment: Yes Eugene.I am unable to proceed because of error at the line that i had mentioned above. The error is Object not found

Comment: Instead of accessing the Store object by its name you need to iterate over all stores. See [Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867405(v=office.15).aspx) object page in MSDN for the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pstxy](http://pantilesoft.github.io/)

It provide a .NET API, which you can iterate over Outlook PST files, and extract mail contents you need.